# Adding additional criteria to Process Builder formula

Tags: process-builder, formula

We have a bypass process when certain emails are sent. I would like to add conditions to the process and I can't seem to get it in a syntax the PB likes.

```
    AND
($CustomMetadata.Process_Builder_Bypass__mdt.Email_Auto_Update_Provided_To_Customer.Bypassed__c, CONTAINS 
($CustomMetadata.Process_Builder_Bypass__mdt.Email_Auto_Update_Provided_To_Customer.Profiles__c,$Profile.Name))
```

These are the two conditions I'd like to add to these criteria

```
([EmailMessage].Parent.Status CONTAINS "TR/CR",
[EmailMessage].Subject CONTAINS "_TR_CR_")
```

I've tried adding it within the other condition and it says Syntax error "Missing ')'

```
AND ($CustomMetadata.Process_Builder_Bypass__mdt.Email_Auto_Update_Provided_To_Customer.Bypassed__c, CONTAINS ($CustomMetadata.Process_Builder_Bypass__mdt.Email_Auto_Update_Provided_To_Customer.Profiles__c,$Profile.Name), 
([EmailMessage].Parent.Status CONTAINS "TR/CR",
[EmailMessage].Subject CONTAINS "_TR_CR_"))
```

When I add this I get "Extra Email Message.Parent.Status", but I added it in the formula builder so I know the syntax is correct.

```
AND ($CustomMetadata.Process_Builder_Bypass__mdt.Email_Auto_Update_Provided_To_Customer.Bypassed__c, CONTAINS ($CustomMetadata.Process_Builder_Bypass__mdt.Email_Auto_Update_Provided_To_Customer.Profiles__c,$Profile.Name)) 
[EmailMessage].Parent.Status CONTAINS "TR/CR",
[EmailMessage].Subject CONTAINS "_TR_CR_"
```

Any pointers to documentation or clues as to how to add this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some good resources:

- [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5)
- [Use Formula Fields](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) && [Advanced Formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas) trailheads
- The `Build Formula` insert actions within the Process Builder (see below). By searching through the functions and clicking insert, you'll see the format for functions.

[image]

There's three things within your example that is off:

1. Parenthesis - if you want all conditions met, make sure they're all within the `AND` function

```
AND (
    ..everything here...
)
```

2. Email `Status` is a picklist field and `CONTAINS` works on text. You'll need to convert the field value into text using `TEXT()`.
3. Your original formula used `CONTAINS` correctly (but your additions did not) and the same format/syntax applies even if using a field instead of a custom metadata value.

[CONTAINS](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) should be in the format of `CONTAINS(text, compare_text)` . If that text is a field, then it's just `CONTAINS(fieldName, compare_text)`.

```
AND(
$CustomMetadata.Process_Builder_Bypass__mdt.Email_Auto_Update_Provided_To_Customer.Bypassed__c,
CONTAINS($CustomMetadata.Process_Builder_Bypass__mdt.Email_Auto_Update_Provided_To_Customer.Profiles__c, $Profile.Name),
CONTAINS(TEXT([EmailMessage].Parent.Status), "TR/CR"),
CONTAINS([EmailMessage].Subject, "_TR_CR_")
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, the syntax works, but the [EmailMessage].Parent.Status field throws this error.

The formula expression is invalid: Field Email Message is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that. That field is a picklist field so you need to convert its value to text to use in contains (which expects text) like so `CONTAINS(TEXT([EmailMessage].Parent.Status), "TR/CR"),`

Comment: Thank you that was the field I needed.